# Customizing a textview

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I want to create a label like this:

[image]

Requirements are:

- The rectangle should grow with the text
- the length of the red line is dependent of a property

What I tried was to create a 9ng image for the background of the text and use the padding property for the length of the red line. The red line is drawn by overriding the onDraw method.

The result is that the red line is correct but the background is expanded including the padding like this:

[image]

What's the best way to do this? Building a custom view with a label included? a custom view drawn 100% programmatically (in this case, what's the method to resize a 9ng image?)?

Thanks
Julien

Comment: Share the view xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/<your_drawable>"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

            <View 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Hum, I tried to do it full programmatically but this solution is nice. I added a wrapper class to store the red line width. Is there a way to draw a dot-line with this method?

Comment: this is the easy way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is probably using two different controllers.

You set a simple `textView` with your rectangle as background and with the width set to `wrap-content`.

After this you create the line positioning her where you want (to the right of the controller or to the end of the page or where you please) and you resize it as you want.

For any doubt I'm here